# Value of structure pointer not being updated

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to implement a function which takes two pointers to a structure `data1` and `data2` and updates their value.

This is what I have tried doing, but I get `Segmentation fault`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data{
    int item;
    int count;
};
typedef struct data data;

void changeVal(data *data1, data *data2, int value)
{
    data *tmp = malloc(sizeof * tmp);

    tmp->item = value;
    tmp->count = 10;

    data1 = tmp;
    data2 = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    data *data1 = NULL;
    data *data2 = NULL;
    
    changeVal(data1, data2, 39);
    printf("%d\n", data1->item);
    
    printf("End");

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I comment the line `printf("%d\n", data1->item);` the program runs properly and I get the output "End". Why is this happening?

***EDIT***

If I have a collection and I pass this to the `changeVal` function, the values get updated. What is happening here?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data{
    int item;
    int count;
};
typedef struct data data;

struct collection{
    data *one;
    data *two;
};
typedef struct collection collection;

void changeVal(collection *cltn, int value)
{
    data *tmp = malloc(sizeof * tmp);
    tmp->item = value;
    tmp->count = 10;
    cltn->one = tmp;
    cltn->two = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    collection *cltn;
    cltn = malloc(sizeof(cltn));
    
    cltn->one = NULL;
    cltn->two = NULL;
    
    changeVal(cltn, 39);
    printf("%d\n", cltn->one->item);
    
    printf("End");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The function should be taking `data**`, and the update should be done `*data1 = tmp;`. Right now you are updating a variable passed by value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But why? Isn't this pointer to a structure? Since I am a beginner, I would request you to please explain the reason behind it.

Comment: Pointers are variables just like anything else. In order your function to update something, it needs to update the *pointee*. That is, to take an *address* which is passed by value, go to that address, and update the value at that address.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why is it happening in the case of arrow operator `cltn->one = temp` in the second scenario? (Consider the edit on my question).

Comment: Because you pass a pointer `cltn` and update what it points to, and not the pointer itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reference in C. There is a different type that holds addresses as its value.

data1 contains A COPY of whatever you passed as parameter. Since you passed an address, it will have a copy of that address, when you make changes in the address that stored there using the operator *, the changes will reflect in the paramteter you called.

Look at the line below:

```
 data1 = tmp;
```

You are altering the address stored in data1, which will no longer be the same as the parameter passed. Once the function is done, data1 no longer exists and the parameter will have its same address.

When you put a second * in the parameter, by using the * inside the function you can alter the address of the variable that was passed to it:

by changing the function signature to:

```
void changeVal(data **data1)
```

and suppose you call:

```
data *d;
changeVal(&d);
```

if you access inside the function with the * operator:

```
*data1 = malloc...
```

it would be the same as if you were using d in main:

```
d = malloc...
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use pass the address of the structure for your purpose as shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data{
    int item;
    int count;
};
typedef struct data data;

void changeVal(data **data1, data **data2, int value)
{
    data *tmp = malloc(sizeof (tmp));
    //make sure to check whether proper memory is allocated
    if(tmp)
    {
        printf("allocated mem for tmp is %u\n", tmp);
        tmp->item = value;
        tmp->count = 10;
        *data1 = tmp;
        *data2 = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    data *data1 = NULL;
    data *data2 = NULL;

    printf("before memory allocation data1 is %u\n", data1);    

    changeVal(&data1, &data2, 39);
    printf("%d\n", data1->item);

    printf("after allocated memory data1 is %u\n", data1);

    // free the allocated memory
    free(data1);
        data1 = NULL;
        data2 = NULL;

    printf("End");

    return 0;
}
```